# What function to use to select text?

Tags: c++, windows, text, clipboard

I search a lot of on internet but didn't find some good copy-paste manager for windows 7. I want to make something to easy copying multiple texts. So my question is what function to use in c++ to select some text that will be copy. The plan is that every time when is pressed CTRL+C selected text copy to some txt file, and when is pressed CTRL+V application show you what is in that file, and you can use what text you need. The main question is how to  select text, what function to use? Platform win 7.

Comment: This question is lacking many essential details, such as what platform are you programming on.

Comment: the platfom is win 7 it is in question

Comment: @raptor: You're essentially asking for a clipboard ring or a clipboard history manager. Have you not tried searching for those?

Comment: @raptor you've been a member here over a year, tag the question with windows if that is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up a bit on how the Windows clip board works. Every application in the system can place objects of different formats (including text) on the clip board. The easiest way to grab the content out of any applications is probably to somehow monitor the clip board and get the data from there.

For the pasting part, if I remember correctly, there is a special kind of "owner-handled" data on the clip board. Using that, the data isn't actually published on the clip board, only a reference to the application currently having the clip board data. Whenever the data is pasted the application gets notified that it should send the data to the recipient. It should be possible to exploit that functionality to get your application to pop up a windows where the user can select what data to paste.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my articles on clipboard viewer implementation, including common pitfalls:
http://www.clipboardextender.com/developing-clipboard-aware-programs-for-windows/6

http://www.clipboardextender.com/developing-clipboard-aware-programs-for-windows/common-general-clipboard-mistakes

Comment: Answers only containing links to external sources are considered bad practice at Stack Overflow. The core concepts of the answers should be written (or copy-pasted) into the answer itself. A link can provide more details.

Comment: The first link tells you what to do, when designing a clipboard viewer. The second link tells you what NOT to do.  Both are much too long to be copy/pasted here.  And I know a thing or two about copy-paste...